# Geometry relating to infinite series

Tags: sequences-and-series, geometry, algebra-precalculus

[image: Figure 1]

For this particular diagram below, is there any reason why all the radii of the circles are in a geometric progression?
I've tried using similar triangle to try and prove it, but was unsuccessful
Any help would be much appreciated

Comment: Hint: similar triangles.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

[image]

In the figure, let $AD=R$ and $BC=r$, then

$DE=R-r$ and $CD=R+r$

$$\therefore  \frac{R-r}{R+r}=\sin \alpha$$

$$R(1-\sin \alpha)=r(1+ \sin \alpha)$$

$$\frac{R}{r}=\frac{1+ \sin \alpha}{1-\sin \alpha}$$

The radii are in geometric progression.